# Can a smd aluminum electrolytic capacitor be replaced with a normal electrolytic cap?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

[image: Board]

I have a JBL Charge 2+ amplifier that during dissasembly I missed a major step and accidentally broke off about 2 to 4 of the SMD electrolytic caps. Instead of buying replacement ones I already have some normal electrolytic caps that aren't surface mounted and I was wondering as long as I find one with the same voltage and µF can I just use them instead? I know the amplifier still works as when I power it up; everything lights up but there's no sound, the amp still connects with bluetooth but I still get no output to the speakers. Can I replace a SMD electrolyteic capacitor with a normal though hole electrolytic capacitor?

Comment: if you can solder them there is no difference IMO

Comment: Can you please highlight the area on the board you are talking about?

Comment: If they are bulk decoupling caps, yes. The fact that they come in an SMD package does not imply that they are somehow "better." Just make sure your replacements are from a reputable manufacturer.

Comment: Depending on what damage was done to the PCB when the original SMD capacitors "broke off", then you might not have any pads left on the PCB to be able to solder anything else instead. I couldn't see where on your photo the missing capacitors should have been, so I can't identify whether this problem applies to you or not. Just beware of the possibility that the pads were ripped off the PCB, attached to the original capacitors.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, with bypass caps they need to have the same ESR. The other problem is the leads from through hole caps will have more parasitic inductance. So make sure the leads are short, and you match the ESR (or have lower ESR) with the new capacitors.

For capacitors that are connected to filters of DC to DC converters, it's best if all specs are matched exactly and the capacitor is installed in the same manner, even trace size or leads can add parasitics that can cause loss or instability in a DC to DC converter.